# Error setuptools when installing tensorflow

Tags: macos, pip, tensorflow

I followed installation instruction at: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#pip_install

I am using python 2.7.11 (Anaconda) on Mac OS X 10.11. I checked but setuptools 18.5 is already installed on my computer.

and met the error

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
The directory '/Users/my_name/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/my_name/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting tensorflow==0.6.0 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
  Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl (10.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.2MB 30kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from tensorflow==0.6.0)
Collecting protobuf==3.0.0a3 (from tensorflow==0.6.0)
  Downloading protobuf-3.0.0a3.tar.gz (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 90kB 2.7MB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in /Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow==0.6.0)
Collecting numpy>=1.8.2 (from tensorflow==0.6.0)
  Downloading numpy-1.10.1.tar.gz (4.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 4.1MB 77kB/s 
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf==3.0.0a3->tensorflow==0.6.0)
  Downloading setuptools-18.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (463kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 466kB 673kB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, numpy, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: setuptools 18.5
    Uninstalling setuptools-18.5:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-18.5
  Rolling back uninstall of setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 242, in move_wheel_files
    name, user=user, home=home, root=root, isolated=isolated
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/locations.py", line 181, in distutils_scheme
    d = Distribution(dist_args)
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 729, in iter_entry_points
    entries = dist.get_entry_map(group)
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2705, in get_entry_map
    self._get_metadata('entry_points.txt'), self
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2448, in parse_map
    for group, lines in data:
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in split_sections
    for line in yield_lines(s):
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2303, in yield_lines
    for ss in strs:
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2630, in _get_metadata
    if self.has_metadata(name):
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1626, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1984, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1864, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1804, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/my_name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg'
```

Comment: I'm no conda expert -- is the usual approach to install without `sudo`? (If you just drop the `sudo` at the start, does that work?)

Comment: Might the problem be related to the version of the protobuf library? The conda library has 2.6.1 only:

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/protobuf

and tensorflow uses 3.0.0.

Comment: Hi @CraigCitro, the tutorial of tensorflow said that we should run with sudo. Actually I did not try without sudo.

Comment: i got it to work but i had to keep running the same commands multiple times in different order lol. wtf?

Answer (score 26):

I had the exact same issue (using Python 2.7.11 (Anaconda) on Mac OS X 10.11).

Adding `--ignore-installed` flag worked for me (as discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/622)).

```
$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl --ignore-installed

$ python
>>> import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 15):

I had similar errors on Ubuntu

> ```
> conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda setuptools
> ```

solved the problem for me

Comment: Worked on my macOS Sierra as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem today and solved it by running the following:

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade tensorflow --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem and solved it by installing the python 3 version of tensorflow. So maybe check if there's a mismatch between your version of python and your version of tensorflow?

Comment: Hi, but I thought that I installed tensorflow for python 2