# Installing Tensorflow with Python 3.5 and Anaconda

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, anaconda

I have Anaconda 3.19.3 with Python 3.5 on a Mac. Now, I would like to install TensorFlow via `pip`. The installation instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html) also include setup instructions for installing TensorFlow under Python 3.3+.

So, I have executed `sudo easy_install --upgrade six`, no problem. When I execute `sudo pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl`, after downloading the necessary packages, I get the following:

```
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, tensorflow
Found existing installation: setuptools 19.6.2
    Uninstalling setuptools-19.6.2:
        Successfully uninstalled setuptools-19.6.2
Rolling back uninstall of setuptools
Exception:
...
AttributeError: _ep_map
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-19.6.2-py3.5.egg'
```

I have left out some of the error message to save space.

What is this and, more importantly, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer here:
[Error setuptools when installing tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264512/error-setuptools-when-installing-tensorflow)

In particular, you could try adding the `--ignore-installed` tag to the end of your pip command.